# Python + GWT

Tags: python, gwt, javascript, java

Пробовал ли кто скрестить python и gwt? Прошу поделиться опытом и мнениями по данному направлению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем с GWT-RPC действительно не будет, так как GWT-RPC просто не будет работать вообще при Python на сервере. GWT-RPC основан на сервлетах, которые естественно требуют среду выполнения Java. Но никто не мешает использовать вам GWT для клиентской части приложения при Python или PHP на сервере.
Вот пример интеграции GWT и PHP с JSON данными: [http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSONphp.html](http://www.jython.org/)

Кстати, не стоит забывать о том, что есть реализация Python на JVM - [Jython](http://www.jython.org/). Вы пишете на языке Python, а компилятор все преобразовывает в байт-код для JVM. В таком образе все будет работать на ура, возможно даже без бубна.

Comment: Нет нет, бубен всё равно понадобится. Jython не генерирует java-классы для python-классов и непросто их замапить. Так что велика вероятность, что придётся делать обёртки на Java, хотя это технически просто, но неприятно.

Answer (score 2):

[Pyjamas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyjamas_(software))

Answer (score 1):

Я какое-то время назад думал о том, чтобы сделать что-то подобное. Меня остановило то, что наверняка будут неприятности с GWT-RPC. За исключением этого, проблем возникать не должно. Разумеется, питон может быть только на серверной стороне.

Comment: Я не уверена, но должно быть GAE на серверной стороне и GWT на клиенте должны работать не зависимо от языка backend (Java или Python), да и Python должен дать выигрыш в производительности. т.е. в таком варианте Python + GWT можно скрестить

Comment: Python может даль выигрыш в производительности далеко не всегда. Все зависит от поставленных задач. Питон быстро стартует и быстро завершается, но не очень уж быстро работает на самом-то деле. Это даст прирост при генерировании мелких страничек и при отсутствии необходимости в фоновой активности на сервере. Кроме того, у питона масса мелких и противных проблем. Например, они до сих пор не привели в порядок кодировки и не разобрались с юникодом.